# How to add os manually to berryboot

Tags: boot, software-installation

How to add os manually to berryboot ? I download some OS from http://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/ on windows computer and I want add to SD card for run multiple OS using one SD card. How to do that ? This is **raspberry pi without connected to the Internet**.

Answer (score 3):

Hold down your mouse button over the “Add OS” button and select “copy OS from USB stick”, to install an operating system saved on USB stick.

Answer (score 2):

BerryBoot is designed to download prepared images from the internet.

If you are a linux user (or you want to dig into it), you can follow [these instructions](http://www.berryterminal.com/doku.php/berryboot/adding_custom_distributions) from the BerryBoot documentation to prepare the images yourself, then put the prepared image to a USB flash drive, plug it in the Raspberry Pi, boot up BerryBoot and add the image through *Add OS* > *Install from USB stick*.

Answer (score 0):

If the raspberry pi is not connected to the internet, you can download the images here:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/berryboot/files/os_images/

Comment: From the question the downloads don't seem to be the problem, but the how to add them to a berryboot SD card and boot loader are.